# CSS: displaying table rows vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I'm working on a very basic script in Ruby on Rails to display the records from a table, about CSS I'm using Flex but it is affecting the display (horizontally) of all items, this is the result:

[image: showdata]

The row in green is the header and the next one contains the data, the HTML code looks like this:

```css
html, body{
         margin: 0;
         background-color: #3a3a3a;
     }
    
     body *{
         color: white;
         font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         flex-direction: row;
         border-radius: 5px;
         align-items: center;
     }
    
     div {
         margin-left: 20px;
     }
    
     input {
         color: black;   
     }
    
     h1{
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }
    .description{
        background-color: rgba(9, 0, 0, 0.199);
        padding: 2em;
        font-size: 2em;
        max-width: 600px;
    }
    .meta *{
        display: flex;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .links *{
        margin-top: 10px;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgb(31, 55, 133);
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #tabledata {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      #tabledata td, #tabledata th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
      }
      
      #tabledata tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
      
      #tabledata tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
      
      #tabledata th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        color: white;
      }
```

```html
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    
    <h1>Productlines</h1>
    
    <table id="tabledata">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Available?</th>
          <th colspan='3'>Options</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
        <% @productlines.each do |productline| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=productline.name %></td>
            <td><%=productline.isactive %></td>        
            <td class="links"><%= link_to 'Show', productline %></td>
            <td class="links"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_productline_path(productline) %></td>
            <td class="links"><%= link_to 'Destroy', productline, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <br>
    
    <span class="links"><%= link_to 'New Productline', new_productline_path %></span>
```

My question is: is there anyway to display the rows inside the table in vertical mode?
Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: try rotating it.

Comment: would you mind giving me an example please? I don't what selector or label should I rotate, Thanks

Comment: "I'm using Flex but it is affecting the display (horizontally) of all items". So don't use flex, or rather not like that. You need to be selective in which elements flex is applied to, just as you would be with any other display value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are applying `flex` to every HTML element in the `body` when using `body *` selector.

The default setting for the flex display property is to layout the elements in the flex container horizontally, because the default value on a flex container is `flex-direction: row;`

For the items you want to have horiztonally add `flex` to the parent element. So if you only want the green items horizontally add the `display:flex` to the `#tabledata` element like this:

```
#tabledata {
    display: flex;
}
```

If you want a more specific answer I would change the code in your question and remove the ruby on rails code, and just add in dummy text so a simple code reproduction can be done by someone answering.

With HTML tables there is actually no reason to use `flex` at all, but again if you amend the question and get rid of the ruby code you'll get more specific answers.

Comment: thanks a lot @Emmy for the explanation